# URL encoding - what difference to SEO? + or _ or -

Tags: seo, url, google-search, clean-urls, url-encoding

I have a URL e.g.:

```
http://mysite.com/tracks/backing-track/101153/ABBA/Super+Trouper
```

**QUESTION** does it make a difference to SEO when using `+` or `-` or `_` in the URL between words? Is one more readable and indexable than the others?

Comment: Google recommends using hyphens instead of underscores: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=76329

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the underscore is not recommended as it could be considered part of a word, whereas the other two are word separators.